# Is it possible to float center an image?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, center

As far as I know in HTML & CSS you can only float an image to the left or right of other elements such as text, not on both sides at once, effectively `float: center`. The text reads across the image.

This is easy enough to do in Word:

[image]

Is there an HTML & CSS way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Floating center like the example you have provided would be considered bad design practise. It essentially leads to a really unpleasant user experience, especially in the day where most websites are responsive and need to work on mobile phones as well as desktops.

E.g. It's not really clear as to wether or not we should continue reading on the same line (on the other side of the image) or start a new line.

I would highly recommend looking into typographic grids and using a grid in your work to ensure legibility and accessibility is optimum!

Comment: More information on typographic grids would be helpful. E.g. how do they work? How do they solve the problem?

Comment: You're best bet is to google this kinda stuff, it's very broad and deep.But essentially a grid is the framework for which all the content sits, it allows for proper alignment, spacing so that all elements can breathe and are legible.

Comment: Typographic grids seem to have nothing to do with HTML. I'm not looking for reasons not to do it, I'm looking for how to do it.

Comment: Okay what I'm saying very simply is this: typographic arrangement is a practise of which can be done well or be done badly. Typographic grids are a good typographic practise. HTML and the web is made primary of typography. Get good at typography = get good at building nice websites.

Comment: Currently, my only way of solving this is to embed an image. I think you'd agree that's a much worse solution!